# Opposite of caregiver

Tags: vocabulary

I want to write a book about the unfair expectations of a caregiver. A caregiver refers to somebody to looks after somebody else.  What is the term for that 'somebody else'.  'Patient' doesn't seem all encompassing.

Comment: Patient is probably most appropriate. Client is a good term as well. After that, it's subjective.

Comment: Notice how _caretaker_ and _caregiver_ mean almost the same thing?

Comment: Opposite of caregiver to me is abuser or tormenter.  Maybe who does caregiver take care of?

Comment: I think KKSim is looking for the complement of "caregiver," not its opposite.

Comment: Maybe we need a neologism *caregetter*?

Comment: @ryebread I hate it when I agree with you.  It's not an opposite, it's an opposite position at best. ABrooks has it right with complement.

Comment: @DavidM - you love agreeing with me.  You are simply complementing yourself for becoming more enlightened.

Comment: @Ryebread Shockingly, I disagree. ;-)  I think frenemies is beginning to describe our interactions rather well.

Comment: @DavidM - I agree with most of your answers but if I accept them then I would need to tie a sweater around my neck and smoke a pipe.

Comment: @Ryebread As a physician I'm obligated to tell you that pipe smoke is bad for you. As a snob, I'm required to tell you that tying your sweater around your neck just marks you as a *member of the illuminati*.  Oops, I've said too much.

Answer (score 12):

**Charge** or **ward** might be appropriate to this meaning.

Patient implies that they have a medical condition that requires looking after.  But, perhaps they merely have a generalized condition requiring constant care.  If it is medically stable and doesn't need any acute treatment, it seems inapt to refer to them as a patient.

Whereas, it would be a perfectly legitimate catchall to say:

> The caretaker spent his time watching over his charge.

This does not imply that their relationship is restricted to being medical in nature.

Answer (score 3):

**Dependent** works whether the caregiver is paid, unpaid, related or unrelated to the disabled individual.

Comment: Talking about someone's dependent immediately makes me think of taxes. The dictionary Google uses says it means there is a financial relationship: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Adependent.

Comment: I think this is the best word.  Dependent means someone reliant on another.

Answer (score 3):

The **care recipient** or **receiver of care** or **person in care** seemed to get used in official language.

The **cared-for** perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

**Charge** is a person or thing committed to the care (meaning in the care) of another. ([source](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charge) at 3d)

Children is day care are called charges.

Answer (score 1):

In the BE version of the care sector, I've heard them called: Clients, Service Users, Residents (of a Care Home / Hospice), and even (occasionally) Caree.

Patients is still common in hospital settings, but not as a form of address where names are used to be assured of the correct treatment reaching it's target.

Comment: +1 because I agree with all of these, but the relationship is not always a profession one.  It could be a relative caring for an invalid relative, etc.

Comment: We still refer to them as care-givers, if the care-giver is below 16 years, it is referred to as a "Tough living Situation". If it's not a professional relationship, I imagine they call each-other all sorts of things, but I've not encountered a specific word describing the recipient of care in this case, with the exception of "invalid", as in "I'm the sole carer of my invalid mum".

Comment: I agree with that part. Just the client, etc is inapt in those cases.

Comment: ok, You see,I am the caregiver , to my husband who suffered a stroke, so he's the 'other name I am looking for.'  However, I'd rather not say he is the care-receiver, he's more like a care-taker, care being the opposite of give (and there-in lies the problem because a caretaker can also be a caregiver, and not the opposite. My Chinese pals just shake their heads and justify their adversity to learning English.